# VC++ Comments, Documentation and IntelliSense

Tags: c++, visual-c++, comments, intellisense

In C#, I comment methods like this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Does absolutely nothing
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a">First useless parameter</param>
    /// <param name="b">Second useless parameter</param>
    /// <returns>zero</returns>
    public int Foo(int a, int b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Which gives very nice IntelliSense hint window:

[image]

What, if any, is the equivalent in Visual C++ or (even better) a solution that would work in other IDEs like XCode or Eclipse?

**Update**

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618571/how-to-write-c-comments-that-show-up-in-intellisense), but @edtheprogrammerguy's answer has good references so I'll leave the questino here here. Also, SO won't let me delete my question.

**Update the Second**

A lot of the C# XML comments (`<summary>`, for instance) work out of the box. It'd be nice if the `///` comment automatically inserted the required `summary`, `param` and `returns` tags, but I imagine that it'd be pretty easy to implement with a new code snippet.

**Update the third**

Here's a code snippet that inserts the header. It doesn't scan the method parameter list, but it's a nice start. Save to `Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Code Snippets\Visual C++\My Code Snippets` as anything with a `.snippet` extension, restart VS, and activate by typing `summ` + TAB above a method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CodeSnippets xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2005/CodeSnippet">
  <CodeSnippet Format="1.0.0">
    <Header>
      <SnippetTypes>
        <SnippetType>Expansion</SnippetType>
      </SnippetTypes>
      <Title>SnippetFile1</Title>
      <Author>dlively</Author>
      <Description>Insert a summary/param/return header for a method</Description>
      <HelpUrl>
      </HelpUrl>
      <Shortcut>summ</Shortcut>
    </Header>
    <Snippet>
      <Declarations>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>summary_text</ID>
          <ToolTip>summary_text</ToolTip>
          <Default>Insert description of method</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>returns_text</ID>
          <ToolTip>returns_text</ToolTip>
          <Default>Description of return value</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>parameter_name</ID>
          <ToolTip>parameter_name</ToolTip>
          <Default>Name of the parameter</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
        <Literal Editable="true">
          <ID>parameter_description</ID>
          <ToolTip>parameter_description</ToolTip>
          <Default>Description</Default>
          <Function>
          </Function>
        </Literal>
      </Declarations>
      <Code Language="cpp" Kind="method decl"><![CDATA[/// <summary>
/// $summary_text$
/// </summary>
/// <param name="$parameter_name$">$parameter_description$</param>
/// <returns>$returns_text$</returns>]]></Code>
    </Snippet>
  </CodeSnippet>
</CodeSnippets>
```

Also, see the very nice [Code Snippet Designer](https://github.com/mmanela/snippetdesigner) VS extension which makes creating these a breeze.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is for producing documentation from the source files.  The `/doc` compiler option will cause it to generate an .xdc file which can be turned into an .xml documentation file.  VC++ is not as nice about Intellisense as C# is.

References:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177227.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173501.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Regarding automatically inserting comment tags by typing ///, I wrote an extension - [CppTripleSlash](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/22333333-fd6f-4dcb-8223-52701eddd7ad) that you might find useful.